# SignalR inside _Layout.cshtml - persist connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

I decided to use SignalR for chat on my page. Chat page is opened when user clicks on "Enter Chat" link which is placed inside _Layout.cshtml. This works fine. However, what I would like to achieve is the following functionality:

- On the left side of the page I would like to have some kind of
  "online users" area and when one user logins, other users whose are
  already logged in will be able to see that a new user just enters the
  page.
- Users who are online can chat with each other by simply
  clicking on their names

I am using the following code to connect to the chat application:

```
$(function () {
            //declare a proxy to reference the hub
            var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
            registerClientMethods(chatHub);
            //Start Hub
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                registerEvents(chatHub);
                chatHub.server.connect(@User.Identity.Name);


            });
        });
```

However when I place this code inside my _Layout.cshtml page, users are permanently logged off and connected again each time they navigate through pages (they are intended to be opened inside _Layout.cshtml). 
Is there any way for persisting connection with the hub when navigating through page? What is the best practices when using this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you navigate away from a page or in any way refresh the contents of the page you will need to start a fresh SignalR connection.  There are two ways to handle this behavior when navigating through pages:

1. Create a single page application.
2. Handle users connecting/disconnecting on the server in such a way that they're not truly logged out until they leave the site.

Now to dive into a little more detail on #2.  Users on your site may disconnect/connect every time they transition to a new page but you can control how they log out or appear disconnected via your server side logic.  You can get this functionality by keeping a set of "online" users in your server side code and then only considering them offline after a specified timeout value.

Comment: ok, I understand, but how can I keep "online" users in server side code? e.g. by making a simple singleton with list of online users?

Comment: That's definitely a valid way yes.

Comment: N.Taylor Mullen - I managed to get the online users. Now what I want to do is to open a new page with a private chat. This works fine. However, is there any way I can notify user2 when user1 starts to chat (e.g. a window with a private chat will open for user2). When this window is opened, I don't want to notify user2 again.

Comment: Of course, that's all just server side logic and triggering the correct server functions at the correct time

Comment: but I was wondering how should I do this? for instance: show div with information if user2 wants to chat with user1? I understand that I should trigger the correct server function but how to trigger client function from the server?

Comment: With SignalR it's as simple as Clients.Client("YourClientsConnectionID").foo(); within a hub